# Is "if not by" equivalent to "if...not" in conditional sentences?

Tags: conditionals

I was looking at an example of a conditional that can't use "unless" in a grammar book:

> "How will children learn about wild animals **if they don't** see them in zoos?"

And thought of a seemingly alternative version of that:

> "How will children learn about wild animals **if not by** seeing them in zoos?"

But is that an actual conditional sentence? Because it sounds like a certainty. If so, is it saying the same thing as the prior one?

Comment: Some people might see a shift of *emphasis* between the two. The first could be ***rhetorical*** - drawing attention to the fact that children ***will not learn*** in a (current, planned, or hypothetical) context where seeing them in zoos is not an available option (perhaps speaker is forcefully arguing that we *should* keep animals in zoos for this very reason). The second might be a more "genuine" question asking what ***alternative*** methods are available (perhaps speaker accepts that zoos are "unethical", and seeks  a different way to introduce children to variety in the animal kingdom).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second sentence is correct and has the same meaning as the first. The second could be considered elliptical (I've put the missing words in double-brackets):

> How will children learn about wild animals if [[they do]] not [[do so]] by seeing them in zoos?

Either sentence could be meant in a serious way (asking a genuine question) or in a rhetorical sense (asking a question in order to make a point). (FF notes in a comment that the first sentence might be more likely to be considered rhetorical than the second. I don't really see that difference between them.)

Comment: Yes, the first one was asked in a rhetorical way in the book. The second one was something that popped into my mind because I've heard people using "if not by" elsewhere. Also I didn't know that was an elliptical phrase, thanks